# Multiprocess vs multithreading for network operations

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I'm building a web scraper that makes multiple requests concurrently. I'm currently using the `multiprocessing` module to do so, but since it's running on a Digital Ocean droplet, I'm running into processor/memory bottlenecks.

Since this is a web scraper and most of the time spent on the script is likely waiting for the network, isn't it more efficient to use threading instead in order to reduce resource usage? Does threading detect a blocking network call and release locks? Is it feasible to intertwine multiprocessing and multithreading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `multiprocessing` module was developed to be largely compatible with the `threading` model that pre-dates it, you should hopefully not find it too difficult to move to threaded operations in a single process.

Any blocking calls (I/O, mostly) will cause the calling thread to be suspended (become non-runnable) and other threads will therefore get chance to use the CPU.

While it's possible to use multi-threading in multiple processes, it isn't usual to do so.